# Not using Messaging systems in CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I have a domain (read) and reporting (write) database on the same machine.

Currently, events are raised and put on an in memory queue and then the corresponding handlers are called to update the reporting database.

What concerns if there is an issue with the reporting database and for some reason writing fails for an event. I suppose this is where NserviceBus etc would be useful but at this stage we do not have the time to invest to look into it.

Now if new events are being raised, should I not process them until I get the problem event processed? Would this be manual intervention? Also other events will all get queued behind the problem event and nothing gets updated in the reporting database.

Also I suppose I need to persist the events just in case the machine goes down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're going to implement your own but poorer NServiceBus in the end. You will not save time this way. NSB is already out there, just read the manual and don't reinvent the wheel.